# SEO Implementation for Dynamic Component Presentations

Tags: content-delivery, search, search-engine

I am rendering Dynamic data on same page (like News Article on Single NewsArticle Page)
Since every time different data is rendered on same page, I can not configure SEO parameters at CMS side using Component or Page Metadata Schema in static fashion.
What are alternatives to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reconsidering your statement of

> I can not configure SEO parameters at CMS side using Component or Page Metadata Schema

You can always read Component Metadata from a DCP, so why not use this approach? Then in your application logic just make sure to read this metadata when assembling the page and rendering it in the right place.

The alternative is to not use DCPs. There's nothing like empowering people to decide which URLs their content should have. And if creating pages is too much work for them (acceptable complaint) then consider automating page creation if there is a 1-to-1 mapping between component & page.

Comment: "Automating page creation" could be event system code, but it's literally a check box to turn a page into a `page type` for Experience Manager.